# Model is not deleted from backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I still trying to remove (destroy) model from my collection. Data is groupedBy and rendered into accordion style. But when I click to X in my console is notice :

```
Uncaught Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of undefined  


   (function() {
    window.App = {
        Models: {},
        Collections: {},
        Views: {},
        Router: {}
    };
    window.vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
})();
```

// !models.js

```
App.Models.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

// !collections.js

```
App.Collections.Items = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Item,
    url: 'api/items.json'
});
```

// !views.js

```
App.Views.Items = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#items',
    events: {
      'click .cccc':'deleteItem',
    },
    deleteItem: function() {
      this.model.destroy();  
    },
    initialize: function() {
     this.listenTo( this.collection, "change", this.render );
     this.template = _.template( document.getElementById('productsCategoriesTemlate').innerHTML );
     this.render();
     this.$el.accordion({ animate: 0 });
    },
    getGroups : function(){
       return _.groupBy(this.collection.toJSON(), 'category');
    },
    render: function() {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.template({ data : this.getGroups() });

    },

    addOne: function(item) {
       // ????????????
    }
});

App.Views.Item = Backbone.View.extend({
      deleteItem: function() {
      this.model.destroy();  
      },

      // ???????????
 });
```

// !router.js

```
App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '':'index',
    },
    index: function() {
        console.log('index page !');
    },
});

new App.Router;
Backbone.history.start();

App.items = new App.Collections.Items;
App.items.fetch().then(function() {
    new App.Views.Items({ collection: App.items });
});
```

**template :**

```
<script id="productsCategoriesTemlate" type="text/template">
    <% _.each( data, function( category, i ){  %>
        <h3 class="category-name"><%= i %></h3>
        <div><% _.each( category, function( item ){ %>
            <li class="product"><%= item.title %><p style="float:right;" class="cccc">X</p></li>
            <% }) %>
        </div>
   <% }) %>
</script>
```

Comment: please show your collection and model

Comment: A Backbone collection has no method `destroy`. Are you looking for `remove`? If so, you need to pass the model you'd like to remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you instantiate `Apps.Views.Items`? Is this your 'collection view'? If this view is representing your collection, you have to somehow pass or reference the model on 'deleteItem'.

`App.Views.Items` does not represent a single model, so `this.model` would be incorrect.

#### UPDATE

You should have a separate view for each item, such as App.Views.Item, and loop through and create this view for each model in App.Views.Items' collection.

#### 2nd UPDATE

Yeah, you are getting it. Here's some sample code I threw together (I haven't tested it, so you might have to adjust it, but it gives a good idea. The template rendering syntax might be incorrect as I don't usually do it manually).

```
App.Views.Items = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(model) {
      var view = new App.Views.Item({ model: model });
      this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    });
  },
});

App.Views.Item = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template($('#itemViewTemplate')),
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
  },
});

App.items = new App.Collections.Items;
App.items.fetch().then(function() {
    var items = new App.Views.Items({ collection: App.items });
    $('body').append(items.render().$el);
});
```

By the way, once you get the hang of Backbone and how it works, you should try out Marionette.js. It makes all of this kind of thing much simpler.

Comment: But I need this collection or models grouped ... how can I make this ? Thanks very very much

Comment: I had before something like you told me but I don't know how implement groupby function there  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18993798/backbone-collection-is-groupedby-but-not-render-doesnt-work